# set GrapqQL date format

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, graphql

I have a mongoDB database in which one field is an ISO date.
When i query the table using a graphql (node) query i receive my objects back all right but the date format i see in graphiql is in this weird format:

```
"created": "Sun Nov 26 2017 00:55:35 GMT+0100 (CET)"
```

if i write the field out in my resolver is shows:

```
2017-11-25T23:55:35.116Z
```

How do i change the date format so it will show ISO dates in graphiql?

the field is just declared as a string in my data type.

**EDIT**
My simple type is defined as:

```
type MyString {
  _id: String
  myString: String
  created: String
}
```

When I insert a value into the base created is set automatically by MongoDB.

When I run the query it returns an array of obejcts. In my resolver (for checking) I do the following:

```
 getStrings: async (_, args) => {
        let myStrings = await MyString.find({});
        for (var i = 0; i < myStrings.length; i++) {
            console.log(myStrings[i]["created"]);
        }

    return myStrings;
}
```

all objects created date in the returned array have the form:

```
2017-11-25T23:55:35.116Z
```

but when i see it in GraphIql it shows as:

```
"created": "Sun Nov 26 2017 00:55:35 GMT+0100 (CET)"
```

my question is: Why does it change format?

Since my model defines this as a String it should not be manipulated but just retain the format. But it doesn't. It puzzels me.

Kim

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your resolver, just return a formatted string using `toISOString()`

```
const date1 = new Date('2017-11-25T23:45:35.116Z').toISOString();
console.log({date1});
// => { date1: '2017-11-25T23:45:35.116Z' }

const date2 = new Date('Sun Nov 26 2017 00:55:35 GMT+0100 (CET)').toISOString();
console.log({date2})
// => { date2: '2017-11-25T23:55:35.000Z' }
```

## UPDATED to answer the added question, "Why does [the date string] change format"?

Mongo does not store the date as a string. It stores the date as a Unix epoch (aka Unix time, aka POSIX time), which is the number of seconds that have elapsed since **January 1, 1970** not counting leap seconds (in ISO 8601: 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z). Since your data model requests a string, it'll coerce the value using `toString()`

```
const date1 = new Date('2017-11-25T23:45:35.116Z').toString();
console.log({date1})
// => { date1: 'Sat Nov 25 2017 15:45:35 GMT-0800 (PST)' }
```

That should clarify the behavior for you, but what you probably really want to do is change your model so that `created` is properly typed as a `Date`. You can do this a couple ways.

1. Create a custom scalar

- [GraphQLScalarType](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqlscalartype)
- [Creating custom scalar types](https://github.com/mugli/learning-graphql/blob/master/7.%20Deep%20Dive%20into%20GraphQL%20Type%20System.md#bonus-creating-custom-scalar-types)

2. Or use an existing package that already does the above for you

- [graphql-date](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-date)
- [graphql-iso-date](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-iso-date)

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to help me. I have edited my question a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do step by step:

1. Set type of your field is Object
2. Insert line `scalar Object` into your .graphql file
3. Add dependence `graphql-java-extended-scalars` into pom.xml file
4. Add syntax `.scalar(ExtendedScalars.Object)` in buildRuntimeWiring function

Let try it.
I try it and successful!